# placeholder not working on text-field input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a newbie in Angular, so my apologies in advance for any silly mistakes. I have defined a textField input through a directive in Angular:

```
.directive('textField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '{{start}}<span class="text-field-cursor">{{end}}</span>',
        controller: 'TextFieldController',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.keyboardOptions.limitTo = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
            scope.keyboardOptions.caps = _.has(attrs, 'caps');

            scope.model = ngModel;

            elem.bind('click', function () {
                scope.openKeyboard();
            });

            elem.on('$destroy', function clickDestroyElement() {
                elem.unbind();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Then, on my HTML, I wrote

```
 <text-field class="text-field" data-t-username focusable request-focus="true" ng-class="{ 'is-focused': (focused || active), 'is-active': active }" ng-model="data.username" placeholder='Enter your username here' limit-to="32"></text-field>
```

However, the placeholder is not being visualized on the web page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: span don't have placeholder . you have to use input control for this

Comment: You've made a custom element, it's not an input anymore, therefore there's no placeholder attribute. In order to do that, you might simulate it manually inside directive, and element on template should be input/textarea.

Answer (score 1):

In your directive, the template isn't an input. So the placeholder can't work.

You can change span to input or other directive who work with placeholder.